# What is the purpose of the string 'provision' parameter in the Vidyo token format?

Tags: video, video-conferencing

In the Introduction of the Developers Documentation, the Format of the token is defined as the following:

```
provision \0 BARE_JID \0 EXPIRES_AT \0 VCARD \0 MAC
```

What is the purpose of the string "provision"?

Answer (score 1):

Vidyo uses "provision token" or just "token" for authentication purposes. When the user of your application wants to connect to a video call, you generate a token on your backend and pass it to the client end application. Your user can then connect to the video call using this token. 
Samples on how to generate tokens can be found on the vidyo website - 
https://developer.vidyo.io/documentation/latest/getting-started#Tokens

There is also a webinar for it on the Vidyo website - https://vidyo.io/blog/events/ondemand-webcast-vidyo-generating-tokens/